# Using Java JAR Library Files In Flutter (dart) Project

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and Dart. I need to know is possible to use JAR library files in a Dart project. The reason for the use of the JAR file is that the JAR file is for my RFID and Barcode scanner API.

Thus I need to import the references and then use them in the dart project. Below is a sample of the JAVA code calling the library files.

package app;

import com.senter.support.openapi.StKeyManager;
import com.senter.support.openapi.StUhf;

public class Activity extends Activity {

```
StKeyManager.ShortcutKeyMonitor monitorScan = StKeyManager.ShortcutKeyMonitor.isShortcutKeyAvailable(StKeyManager.ShortcutKey.Scan) ?
        StKeyManager.getInstanceOfShortcutKeyMonitor(StKeyManager.ShortcutKey.Scan) : null;

private boolean isScaning;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (monitorScan != null) monitorScan.reset(this, listener, null);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    doRFID();
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK: {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                doRFID();
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

StKeyManager.ShortcutKeyMonitor.ShortcutKeyListener listener = new StKeyManager.ShortcutKeyMonitor.ShortcutKeyListener() {
    public void onKeyDown(int keycode,int repeatCount,StKeyManager.ShortcutKeyMonitor.ShortcutKeyEvent event){
        if(isScaning==false){
            isScaning=true;
            doRFID();
        }
    }

    public void onKeyUp(int keycode,int repeatCount,StKeyManager.ShortcutKeyMonitor.ShortcutKeyEvent event){
        isScaning=false;
    }

};

public void doRFID() {
    if(App.getUhf(StUhf.InterrogatorModel.InterrogatorModelD2) == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Device not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {

        TextView editText = this.findViewById(R.id.textRFID);
        TextView editTextRaw = this.findViewById(R.id.textRFIDRAW);
        TextView editTextGTIN = this.findViewById(R.id.textRFIDGTIN);
        textRFID.setText("");
        textRFIDRAW.setText("");
        textRFIDGTIN.setText("");
        ScanRfid scanner = new ScanRfid(this, editText, editTextRaw, editTextGTIN);
        scanner.startScan();
    }
}
```

}

//The following part is where I call the Java code:

//ScanRfid scanner = new ScanRfid(this, editText, editTextRaw, editTextGTIN);
//            scanner.startScan();

Thank you for the help.